# How to use a while read filename; do to take filenames strip "(-to the end" and then create a directory with that information?

Tags: bash

I have hundreds of movies saved as "Title (year).mkv".  They are all in one directory, however, I wish to create a directory by just using the "Title" of the file and then mv the filename into the newly created directory to clean things up a little bit.

Here is what I have so far:

```
dest=/storage/Uploads/destination/
find "$dest" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "%P\n" | sort -n | {
while read filename ; do
echo $filename;
dir=${filename | cut -f 1 -d '('};
echo $dir;
# mkdir $dest$dir;
# rename -n "s/ *$//" *;
done;
}
```

~

```
dest=/storage/Uploads/destination/
```

is my working dirctory

```
find $dest -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 type f -printf "%P\n" | sort -n | {
```

is my find all files in $dest variable

```
while read filename ; do
```

as long as there's a filename to read, the loop continues

```
echo $filename
```

just so I can see what it is

```
dir=${filename | cut -f 1 -d '('};
```

dir = the results of command within the {}

```
echo $dir;
```

So I can see the name of the upcoming directory

```
mkdir $dest$dir;
```

Make the directory

```
rename -n "s/ *$//" *;
```

will rename the pesky directories that have a trailing space
And since we have more files to read, starts over until the last one, and

```
done;
}
```

When I run it, I get"

```
./new.txt: line 8: ${$filename | cut -f 1 -d '('}: bad substitution
```

I have two lines commented so it won't use those until I get the other working.  Anyone have a way to do what I'm trying to do?  I would prefer a bash script so I can run it again when necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `echo` to pass the filename string to `cut` as `dir=$(echo "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d '(')
`

Comment: Thank you very much!  This does exactly what I was asking but cdarke's answer is more streamlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir=${filename | cut -f 1 -d '('};` is invalid.  To run a command and capture it's output use `$( )` and `echo` the text into the pipe.  By the way, that `cut` will leave a trailing space which you probably don't want.

But don't use external programs like `cut` when there is no need, `bash` expansion will do it for you, and get rid of the trailing space:

```
filename="Title (year).mkv"

#  remove all the characters on the right after and including <space>(
dir=${filename%% (*}
echo "$dir"
```

Gives

```
Title
```

General syntax is `%%`*pattern* to remove the longest *pattern* from the right.  Pattern uses the glob (filename expansion) syntax, so `(*` is a space, followed by `(` followed by zero or more of any character.

`%` is the shortest pattern, and `##` and `#` do the same but remove from the left of the pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly what I was looking for.